# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Select statement Sqlite Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am fetching the values from sqlite database in my iOS application. I have written a Select statement like stringquery = "Select * from tablename" and executing it using

database.Query < table > (stringquery);

and assigning the values to the properties in a class. The class has properties with the same name that the columns has in the table in sqlite database.

as the above statement executes i am getting error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Please suggest the solution this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You vaguely describe what you're doing but never say what the problem is.

Comment: @deckertron_9000 if you read the title and description both you will know what i am doing and what is problem. But for your understanding i am editing the question.

Comment: When the exception is thrown, which object does the exception say is null?

Comment: when it executes the code **database.Query < table > (stringquery);**

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are initializing the SQLite Database incorrectly. I've added code below that shows how to implement a SQLite Database in Xamarin.Forms.

This Xamarin.Forms app, contains a fully implemented SQLite Database:
https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp

## ISQLite.cs

Create this file in the Xamarin.Forms PCL. It allows us to access the iOS and Android File Systems to create our Database Connection

```
using SQLite;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public interface ISQLite
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();
    }
}
```

## SQLite_Android.cs

Create this file in the Android project. It returns the Android file path for our SQLite Database Connection.

```
using System.IO;

using SampleApp.Droid;

using SQLite;

using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]
namespace SampleApp.Droid
{
    public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
    {
        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "DatabaseFileName.db3";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

            var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);

            // Return the database connection 
            return conn;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

## SQLite_iOS.cs

Create this file in the iOS project. It returns the iOS file path for our SQLite Database Connection.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using SQLite;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using SampleApp.iOS;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_iOS))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class SQLite_iOS : ISQLite
    {
        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "DatabaseFileName.db3";
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
            string libraryPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", "Library"); // Library folder
            var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);

            var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);

            // Return the database connection 
            return conn;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

## SampleModelDatabase.cs

Create this file in your Xamarin.Forms PCL

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using SQLite;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public static class SampleModelDatabase
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        static readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        static bool _isInitialized;
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public static async Task<IList<SampleModel>> GetAllItemsAsync()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
                await Initialize();

            return await _database.Table<SampleModel>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public static async Task<int> SaveItemAsync(SampleModel model)
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
                await Initialize();

            return await _database.InsertOrReplaceAsync(model);
        }

        public static async Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(SampleModel model)
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
                await Initialize();

            return await _database.DeleteAsync(model);
        }

        public static async Task<int> GetNumberOfRowsAsync()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
                await Initialize();

            return await _database.Table<SampleModel>().CountAsync();
        }

        static async Task Initialize()
        {
            await _database.CreateTableAsync<SampleModel>();
            _isInitialized = true;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments.  This looks like something I've seen elsewhere so let me ask... is this code/approach you provided using the "sqlite-net-pcl", or is it using the "microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite" nuget package?  The reason I ask is that 1) I'm trying to use the Microsoft one, and 2) no example shows it using a "connection" object and there is no "table" in the auto-complete dot notation as you've shown here.

Comment: Hi @Donna! This uses sqlite-net-pcl: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem as you. I found out that the point is database connection, a process that takes time, hasn't completely finished at the moment I started my query. so the solution will be something like:

```
await Connectdb();
// now do your query
var treatment = _database.Query<ClassName>("SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE ...");
```

where the `Connectdb()` is a function that does:

```
DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().DbConnection();
```